# How to implement window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler() in Flutter web project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I know `window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler` works well in javascript, but How to use it in Flutter web project? Yes, the project is a Flutter web project, not written by Javascript.
This is sample code:

```js
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('foo').then(function(result) { 
    console.log('foo_result: ' + result); 
});
```